# Why is policykit-1, agetty and qemu-ga running on a VPS server?

Tags: qemu, policykit

I didn't check my Ubuntu VPS server for a while and I can't remember these processes running displayed by `ps aux`:

```bash
root      1074  0.0  0.1  14664  2032 ttyS0    Ss+   2020   0:00 /sbin/agetty -o -p -- \u --keep-baud 115200,38400,9600 ttyS0 vt220
root      1079  0.0  0.0  14888  1688 tty1     Ss+   2020   0:00 /sbin/agetty -o -p -- \u --noclear tty1 linux
root      1084  0.0  0.1 288868  3456 ?        Ssl   2020  78:30 /usr/lib/policykit-1/polkitd --no-debug
root      1124  0.0  0.0  23056   696 ?        Ss    2020   0:00 /usr/sbin/qemu-ga --daemonize -m virtio-serial -p /dev/virtio-ports/org.qemu.guest_agent.0
```

Can someone explain why they are running or what they are doing? Is it safe to uninstall them?

Comment: I think you should find out what they used for ... Then you would be able to determine if they can be removed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let start here:

1. ***Policykit-1:***

> polkit is a necessary element in all Ubuntu Desktop (GUI) systems. Removing polkit will destroy your Ubuntu Desktop (GUI) system. It's generally not needed if you run headless (without GUI / Ubuntu Server), though folks do sometimes add software that needs polkit.

- **So for a VPS, it wouldn't be useful**.

2. ***Qemu-ga:***

> QEMU Guest Agent. The QEMU guest agent runs inside the guest and allows the host machine to issue commands to the guest operating system using libvirt, helping with functions such as freezing and thawing filesystems. The guest operating system then responds to those commands asynchronously.

- **Are you running a guest OS inside the VPS?**

3. ***Agetty:***

- Helpful: https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/92286/strange-agetty-process-running-on-my-vps

> Apparently agetty is an 'alternate getty' that is used for accessing a system via a serial console, or at least that's my understanding. So it seems that there is no legitimate reason for these processes to be running on my server. I emailed my provider about it, and they said that unless I configured this, it should not be running, and that it has nothing to do with their systems. That leads me to think that someone is trying to hack my server (again).

- **So apparently this isn't needed, but reach out to your provider to be sure.**

The three don't seem to be needed and like the **agetty** quoted snippet from another user with a similar issue did, you may want to contact your provided for further clarification, then proceed to do the needful.

Comment: Thank you! I asked my provider and they indeed installed these processes to make their server interface work!